# How to save cookie-like data without using the database and cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

I am not sure whether this is exclusive to wordpress or not. I am trying to overwrite some user data that appears to be stored in a cookie. For guests it's only a cookie, but for registered users it's also stored somewhere else and it takes priority over the cookie, even if I delete it or set a new one. It does change when I edit it from the place it's supposed to be edited, but I exported the entire database before and after doing so and there is no change. Is there a way to save data that persists between pages and takes priority over cookies and doesn't use the database?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `local storage` get data from `server` and save it in local storage. the data will be available between pages.
check this out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

hope it helps :)

Comment: I didn't know about this storage method, thanks. But I set the localStorage, sessionStorage, and the cookie, then refreshed the page, and everything was back the way it was before I made the changes.